# Why can't I create a dictionary<string, dictionary<string,string>>?

Tags: c#, dictionary

i want to create a dictionary like:

```
Dictionary<string,<Dictionary<string, string>>>
```

Why can't I?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One too many sets of `<>`.

What you want is this:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>
```

Comment: wow, on your way to having a "nice answer" in less than 10 minutes.

Comment: notice however in the OP's question **title**, he has the syntax correct?

Comment: Yep, probably a copy/paste from his code into the question body, but typed the title and simply hadn't seen the mistake in code.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string, string>>
```

2nd parameter is not a `generic` so to speak

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string, string>> 
    = new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string, string>>();
```